# Prevent Bash From Breaking Quoted String

Tags: bash

I wrote a shell script, `agit`, that I use to loop through subdirectories (using `pushd` / `popd`) and perform a git command on each one. I've run into difficulty when I try to do a commit with the `-m` switch. If I type

```
 agit --debug -u commit -a -m "This is a test commit"
```

`--debug` causes, among other things, `set -x` just before the git call and `-u` only performs the call on subdirectories with uncommitted changes.

I get back

```
> git commit -a -m "This is a test commit"

+ git commit -a -m '"This' is a test 'commit"'
fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.
```

The first line is just an `echo` command showing what I expect to happen and the second is what actually gets processed by Bash. I assume the error is because only the first word after `-m` is treated as a message while the remaining words are treated as paths.

As part of my command parsing, I read through each argument, find any containing spaces, and wrap them in quotes.

```
while [[ ${#@} > 0 ]]; do
    _1=${1}
    if [[ "${1}" == *" "* ]]; then
        _1="\"${1}\""
    fi
    _AT="$(append "${_AT}" "${_1}")"
    shift
done
```

On iteration through each of the subdirectories, I simply use

```
git ${_AT}
```

I have tried using `sed` to escape spaces, using single quotes instead, and not changing the arguments at all, all with the same result.

Is there anything I can do to prevent `bash` from breaking up the argument containing spaces?

You can see the full script on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GEaW5pph).

Comment: Use `printf "%q"` and use bash arrays. ( `_AT`? `append`? why not `+=` ?)

Comment: The quotes you add in the assignment to `_1` are literal quotes, not syntactic quotes, and don't protect whitespace from word-splitting in the unquoted expansion of `${_AT}`. You need to use an array if you want to build up a list of command arguments correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap arguments using `printf "%q"`. It's just for that (if you have to do it....):

```
rick() {
    local idx=1 i
    for i; do
        echo "\$$idx=\"$i\""
        ((idx++))
    done
}

morty_pass() {
    eval rick $(printf "%q " "$@")
}

morty_pass "this is a test commit" "second arg"
```

will output:

```
$1="this is a test commit"
$2="second arg"
```

From your command:

```
agit --debug -u commit -a -m "This is a test commit"
```

You probably just use two shifts. Then you can pass `"$@"` to git commit.

```
agit() { 
     arg="$1" # --debug
     # parse debug
     shift;
     arg="-u"
     shift
     git "$@" # will run as expected
}
```

If you have to, use bash arrays:

```
 args=()
 while (($#)); do
      args+=("$1")
      shift
 done 
 git "${args[@]}"
```

But really this is just:

```
args=("$@")
git "${args[@]}"
```

Note, I am surprised that `${#@}` even works. Looks like a funny bash quirk. Use just `$#` for the count of arguments.

Comment: `${#@}` and `${#*}` are explicitly undefined by POSIX; `dash`, for instance, first expands either to a delimited string before returning the length of that string. `bash` explicitly equates both with `$#` (probably for consistency with `${#array[@]}` and `${#array[*]}`).

Answer (score 0):

instead of `while [[ ${#@} > 0 ]]; do` try `for arg in "$@"; do` using $arg as the next argument. The quoted args array `"$@"` prevents a quoted argument from being split